# Auto move Horizontal scroll bar to right end in div

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div which is in the fixed header table format which has more than 24 columns.

The table contains columns in ascending order and it has a horizontal and vertical scroll bar.

So I need to move the horizontal scroll bar of div to right end during the loading. I'm using angular 7 for frontend.

I have tried by using javascript `scrollIntoView` but it is not working.

Anyone suggest me a way to achieve this using angular or javascript but not jquery.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure JavaScript, using the `Element.scrollLeft` and `Element.scrollWidth` properties in combination.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth).

Something like this should work.

```
myDivElement.scrollLeft = myDivElement.scrollWidth;
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating the technique](https://jsfiddle.net/oumqkevs/).

Not tested thoroughly though, and also not sure about browser compatibility and minor tweaks. Use this just as an initial hint.

Answer (score 2):

HTML DOM Scrollleft property would do the trick.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollleft.asp